# Running scripts in the future - date retrieved from database

Tags: php, python, mysql

So what I want to do is execute a script in the future. As an example, I want the user to select a date they want to be emailed. On that date, my program will email the user.

How can I store the future time the program should be executed in a database and retrieve it efficiently? I'm just looking for theory here.

If you're curious, I'll be using MySQL and The scripts will be in Python.

Comment: You probably want [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: put a date in the db. run a periodic cron job--if the date in the db < now, then fire reminder or whatever.

Comment: If you'll be using MySQL and the scripts will be in Python, what does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) in the db. run a periodic [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job--if the date in the db < now, then fire reminder or whatever.